# Apache solr search words, but the search pages yield no results

Tags: search

I have Drupal 7 set up with Search API and Apache Solr.  It was working for a while but after a lot of configuration has been done, modules installed, etc.  The search no longer yields results.  I added solr auto complete to my search block that uses the solr search, and when I start typing in "pizza" it shows that there are indeed two results that come from that search, but when I click Submit, the search page says there are no results.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working?

EDIT: I also have facet search enabled.  To troubleshoot I disabled the facet api entirely and I'm getting the same issue.

EDIT2: Let me know what other information is needed to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had added the line as suggested here:
http://www.druplitec.de/partial-substring-search-using-solr-server-and-searchapi-module

I took out the line and now it works.  I guess I have to find another way to get "fuzzy search" for the solr server to work...

I had added the line to the wrong place.  I re-read through the apache solr docs and found the correct places for it to go.